# Does vsce need separate PAT for Windows and mac for the same project?

Tags: vscode-extensions, personal-access-token

I have a VS Code extension which I do publish from a Windows system which works fine.

Now I cloned the repo on my mac and when trying to publish using
`vsce publish`. It is asking for a Personal Access Token.

My questions are:

- Do we need separate PAT for Windows and Mac?
- I already have added a PAT for Windows system, can I copy that (if possible, which I assume not possible)
- Do I need to create one more PAT in Mac and does this invalidate the Windows PAT?
- If I have to create separate PAT, then how to configure PAT in Mac so it does not ask every time, like in Windows do not ask.

Comment: I think the configuration should be the same in both system, just use `vsce login`